# blockchain.info seems to source transaction money from an address not in my wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions

Today, I have send a transaction with too low a fee:

https://blockchain.info/tx/84eb8a6c6562a9cfedc0e82c7fbe3355615b8154e376db0a325b4ae4f26180b2

I have retrieved the twelve word pass phrase from my wallet on blockchain.info, and calculated the private keys for the addresses in my wallet. However, the address

[1PUBmT2fzVMtNWg58K67knqoz58MmCJ8pn](https://blockchain.info/address/1PUBmT2fzVMtNWg58K67knqoz58MmCJ8pn)

is not amongst these, and it is also the only address that does not show up in my blockchain.info wallet. Therefore it I can only double-spend part of my first transaction (so to void it). What is happening here?

Comment: these are derived from the pass phrase that I got from blockchain.info

Comment: I'm just curious about *how* you derive keys from the passphrase.

Comment: I'd guess the transaction will probably be processed even if it takes a few days.

Comment: Did you input any private keys to your wallet? If so, those private keys won't be able to be generated from the wallet seed (the twelve word pass phrase).

Comment: @MaxVernon the bip39 tool on github

Comment: @HighlyIrregular No, I didn't, I'm quite puzzled by this

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the address in question is a change address. Change addresses are generated using a different key derivation path than your other addresses so you will not see it if you only generated the keys at only one derivation path.

The "normal" key derivation path (a.k.a the "external keychain") is `m/44'/0'/0'/i`. However keys for change addresses are typically generated on a so called "internal keychain" which has a derivation path of `m/44'/0'/1'/i`. It is likely that you only looked at keys on the external keychain and not the internal keychain so you did not see this address.